# Using first element of array or as is if object is not an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, dynamic

Let's assume method a can return either an array or a single element

```
def a(n)
  if n == 0
    return '0'
  else
    return '1', '2'
  end
end

irb(main):008:0> a(0)
=> "0"
irb(main):009:0> a(1)
=> ["1", "2"]
```

What would be the best "ruby" way to express the following:

```
irb(main):013:0> a(0).<???>.to_i
=> 0
irb(main):014:0> a(1).<???>.to_i
=> 1
```

I'm looking for an elegant syntax to achieve the above. I obviously can implement a function what would do dynamic type inspection and would either return the first element of just the input variable as is..

Comment: You say below that you control the definition of `a`, so one must ask: Why not make it always return the same type? You'll save yourself a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 4):

You could cast it into an array using `Array()`:

`Array(a(n)).first`

```
> Array(["1","2"]).first
 => "1" 
> Array("0").first
 => "0"
```

A better solution (if you controlled `a(n)`) would be to return a consistent type from your method.

Comment: Array().first is an interesting solution, thanks. I am controlling a(n). But I'm wondering if the dynamism of ruby doesn't encourage such implementations.

Comment: Just because Ruby allows to return different types, doesn't mean that it is a good practice or that it leads to readable, understandable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) to assign only the first value to a variable:

```
x, = a(0) #=> "0"
x         #=> "0"

x, = a(1) #=> ["1", "2"]
x         #=> "1"
```

`x, = ...` is equivalent to `x, * = ...` or `(x, *) = ...`

Or as a helper method with [array decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) (other link, extra parentheses are required here):

```
def first((x, *))
  x
end

first a(0) #=> "0"
first a(1) #=> "1"
```

---

A different approach is to `yield` the values:

```
def a(n)
  if n == 0
    yield '0'
  else
    yield '1', '2'
  end
end

a(0) { |x| x } #=> "0"
a(1) { |x| x } #=> "1"

a(0) { |*args| args } #=> ["0"]
a(1) { |*args| args } #=> ["1", "2"]
```

This also works nicely with [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html):

```
def a(n)
  return enum_for(:a, n) unless block_given?
  if n == 0
    yield '0'
  else
    yield '1', '2'
  end
end

a(0).next        #=> "0"
a(1).next        #=> ["1", "2"]

a(0).next_values #=> ["0"]
a(1).next_values #=> ["1", "2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with all the comments that this is not a great idea.

Technically `a(n)[0].to_i` works in both cases

```
a(0)[0].to_i
#=> 0
a(1)[0].to_i
#=> 1
```

`String#[]` returns the nth character in the same fashion that `Array#[]` returns the nth element.

Based on your example even if the first return was a `Fixnum` rather than a `String`. `Fixnum#[]` would still work :) but only because `0[0]` returns the  bit reference which just so happens to be `0`

This is what duck typing is all about but it has its caveats such as if `a(0)` was to return `2` instead of `'0'` then you would get `0` e.g. `2[0].to_i #=> 0` because the binary representation is `10` and you are asking for the least significant bit. (first position from the right).

Since you have full control of what `a` actually is it makes more sense to maintain consistency in the return value from `a`. It also makes documenting the method far simpler.

```
def a(n) 
  n == 0 ? ['0'] : ['1','2']
end
```

Comment: I believe this only works when `a(0)` returns a single character: `def a(n);  n == 0 ? '10' : ['1','2']; end; a(0)[0] #=> "1"` .

Comment: @caryswoveland not a single character perse eg '01' still works I just stated that technically `a(n)[0]` worked for the given use case.

Comment: `Array#[]`, `String#[]` and `Integer#[]` are false friends in this case. Although the methods share the same syntax, they are semantically quite different. I'd say it "curiously" works rather than "technically" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
def a(n)
  n.zero? ? '0' : '10', '20'
end

[*a(0)].first #=> "0"
[*a(7)].first #=> "10"
```